# Error adding external JavaScript files in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I hope they are doing very well!
I have had a problem with the import of external libraries in a React project, I hope you can guide me to solve it.

I am doing the import of these libraries in the following way within the App.js.

```
   componentDidMount(){
     let scripts = [
         { src: "./assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" },
         { src: "./assets/js/popper.min.js" },
         { src: "./assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" },
         { src: "./assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js" },
         { src: "./assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js" },
         { src: "./assets/js/aos.js" }
     ];

     scripts.forEach(item => {
         const script = document.createElement("script");
         script.src = item.src;
         script.async = true;
         document.body.appendChild(script);
     })
  }
```

The problem is that when compiling on localhost the following error occurs. I understand that they do not find the file paths that is why it gives the error. However, the file if I have it in that path. (happens to me with everyone)

[image: console error]

Comment: overall you don't need jquery with React + other libraries have convenient react boundings, for example react-bootstrap, etc.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is not in resolving the paths? Find requests for the files in the Chrome Dev tool and see which URLs are there.

Comment: In general, you shouldn't interact directly with the DOM in react (because it uses a Virtual DOM). Use the render function instead [this should help](http://jamesknelson.com/react-js-by-example-interacting-with-the-dom/)

Comment: Thanks! I understand, this solution was following. https://medium.com/better-programming/4-ways-of-adding-external-js-files-in-reactjs-823f85de3668